# How to read file with module classloader in JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, file, jboss, wildfly, classloader

After build I have ear file. Also in ear I have property file: *my.ear\APP-INF\classes\resources\schemas\property.json*. And I need to read this file in my code. How can I do that, cause :

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                      .getResourceAsStream("resources/schemas/" + schemaArray[i])
```

Always return `null`. The class when I try to do that is loaded with `ModuleClassLoader` and I suppose it is the main issue. In the WebLogic server the same code works good and classloader: `weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@4b36a40b`

Answer (score -1):

I found solution here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1145823 helped me

APP-INF/classes can be added to the classpath using a jboss-deployment-structure.xml, which is JBoss specific as shown below:

Raw

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <resources>
      <resource-root path="APP-INF/classes" />
    </resources>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```